# JIRA query for issues without parents

Tags: sql, jira

I'm using a JIRA instance for which I'm not the admin, so I don't have the option of installing plugins.  I'm trying to filter to find issues in a particular project that don't have a parent (aren't sub-tasks of something else), but I can't figure out a good way to do so.  The following query returns issues with a particular parent with the ID 84, but I'm not sure how to tweak it to get issues with no parent:

```
project = FOO AND Status = Open AND parent = FOO-84
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible since doing "parent = null" or "" will tell you that the parent field doesn't support empty value search.

However, to get a list of top level issues you can use the issueType field this way:

```
project = FOO AND Status = Open AND issuetype in standardIssueTypes()
```

To get a list of subtasks:

```
project = FOO AND Status = Open AND issuetype in subTaskIssueTypes()
```

Comment: Cool, works for me.  In our case we use Improvements as top level tasks and Technical Tasks as subtasks by convention, so I was able to use "project = FOO AND issuetype in standardIssueTypes() AND issuetype != Improvement AND Status = Open" to get what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone searching, this is my JQL:

```
issuetype = Task AND issueLinkType != "Child to" ORDER BY created DESC
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Error: "The link type 'Child to' does not exist."

Comment: Use the link type "Child of", that works fine for me.

issueLinkType != "Child of"

Answer (score 0):

The above didn't work for me. Here is another way to get un-parented tasks:

```
issuetype in StandardIssueTypes() AND parent is null
```

Here is how to get un-parented subtasks.

```
issuetype in subTaskIssueTypes()  AND parent is null
```

You can filter our 'Done' statuses by adding the below to any JQL

```
AND status NOT IN (Done)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still looking for a working JQL that only displays issues that have no parent yet:

```
issuetype in StandardIssueTypes() AND issueLinkType != parent ORDER BY created DESC
```

You can of course replace `in StandardIssueTypes()` by a specific issue type like a task. The query will then be:

```
issuetype = Task AND issueLinkType != parent ORDER BY created DESC
```

If you don't want to order, please remove:

```
'ORDER BY created DESC'
```